# How do I avoid Flow-type warnings for React componentDidUpdate?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

My componentDidUpdate method is giving the following error:

> Incompatible override, should have signature: '(prevProps: ReadOnly
>
> , prevState: ReadOnly, _prevContext: any): void

I tried making that the return type, but then I run into errors:

- ReadOnly, P, S: Could not resolve name
- preContext: Incompatible override, should have type 'any'

Code:

```
class EditableCell<ID_TYPE> extends React.Component<Props<ID_TYPE>, State> {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps: ReadOnly<P>, prevState: ReadOnly<S>, _prevContext: any): void {...}

    ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Webstorm, go to Settings -> Editor -> Inspections and turn off 'Signature mismatch' checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidUpdate` expects the component props as the first argument and the component state as the second argument. Therefore, the types should be set accordingly.

Looks to me the end result should be like this:

`componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Props<ID_TYPE>, prevState: State, _prevContext: any)`

Comment: If I try that, I still get, "Incompatible override, should have type ReadOnly<p>". "Incompatible override, should have type ReadOnly<p>". If I add ReadOnly, it can't resolve the name and prevContext still says: Incompatible override, should have type any.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$ReadOnly` special type of Flow: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-readonly